# YouTube Javascript embed won't load until page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, embed, pageload

I have a youtube video called from a Javascript snippet. The functionality allows for chapter selection onClick - allows user to play the video at different times (startSeconds) - the video wont load until o refresh the page, or at random. The first time i load the page, no dice. Nothing shows up in Console and I've tested it with the same result in Chrome and Safari.

my code:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
  width: '800',
  videoId: 'YQY9BZBrZds',
  events: {
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange    
  },
  playerVars:{
    rel: 0,
    wmode: "opaque"
  }         
});
}

function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
if (evt.data == 0) {
      $('#video_popup').removeClass('hide_pop');
      $('#video_popup').addClass('display_pop');
}
else if (evt.data == -1) {
      $('#video_popup').removeClass('display_pop');
      $('#video_popup').addClass('hide_pop');
}
else {
      $('#video_popup').removeClass('display_pop');
      $('#video_popup').addClass('hide_pop');
 }
 }

function chapter1() {
//player.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'YQY9BZBrZds', 'startSeconds': 0});
  player.cueVideoById('YQY9BZBrZds', 0);
  player.playVideo();
}

function chapter2() {
//player.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'YQY9BZBrZds', 'startSeconds': 22});
player.cueVideoById('YQY9BZBrZds', 22);
player.playVideo();
}

function chapter3() {
//player.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'YQY9BZBrZds', 'startSeconds': 44});
player.cueVideoById('YQY9BZBrZds', 44);
player.playVideo();
}

function chapter4() {
//player.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'YQY9BZBrZds', 'startSeconds': 87});
player.cueVideoById('YQY9BZBrZds', 87);
player.playVideo();
}

function chapter5() {
 //player.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'YQY9BZBrZds', 'startSeconds': 149});
player.cueVideoById('YQY9BZBrZds', 149);
player.playVideo();
}
```

My site:
[Click here](http://design.vast42.com/rcity/redux/)
http://design.vast42.com/rcity/redux/

As you can see, under the 1 2 3 instructions is where the video lives.

I got this code fro ma previous S.O. post / JSBin:
[Link to source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239518/youtube-api-loadvideobyid-startseconds-not-working)
[YouTube API loadVideoById startSeconds not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239518/youtube-api-loadvideobyid-startseconds-not-working)

Thank you to anyone who can provide insight!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use cueVideoById. This function add the video to the cue of your player. Yet it is the same video.

> This function loads the specified video's thumbnail and prepares the player to play the video.

You should use the function seekTo.It will make your video to the right position without to reload the video.

> Seeks to a specified time in the video. If the player is paused when the function is called, it will remain paused. If the function is called from another state (playing, video cued, etc.), the player will play the video.

Documentation : https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#seekTo

Your function should look like :

```
function chapter1() {
    player.seekTo(0);
}
```